# Use Keyboard Maestro to move the cursor one space forward

Tags: keyboard-maestro

In ST3 (OS X)  I use shift+space to move the cursor one space forward, i.e. with something like:

```
{ "keys": ["shift+space"], "command": "move", "args":  {"by": "characters", "forward": true} },
```

I find myself wanting to use this in other applications too. I thought I could use [Keyboard Maestro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) to write a macro that did this, but haven't got very far. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Keyboard Maestro there is a 'Simulate Keystroke' action that you could use to do that.

Create a new macro, triggered by 'Hot Key Trigger', and set your hot key.
Add a new action, 'Simulate Keystroke', and set the keystroke.

Here's a screenshot of the test macro I made:

[image: Simulate Keystroke Action]